# Centering Menu on Screen

Tags: html, css, format

I have been working on centering a menu on a webpage I've been working on.  I have tried all the popular answers of display:inline-block, centering the text, margin: 0 auto; however, all attempts have failed.  Is there something that I am doing wrong, or putting the css rules under the wrong elements?

Just wanting a horizontal center alignment.  i have also used a css reset.

I have included a JS Fiddle at my latest failed attempt.  Thank you.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h263kmf2/3/)

```
<div id="menu">

    <ul> 
       <li>
         <a href="#">Apples</a> 
       </li> 
       <li>
         <a href="#">Oranges</a>
       </li> 
    </ul> 

</div>
```

```css
#menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}   

#menu ul{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}


#menu li{
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:75px;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:150px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000;
    float: left;
}

#menu a{
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Centering horizontally **and** vertically ?

Comment: Sorry just horizontally.

Comment: You mean like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/h263kmf2/6/

Comment: Yes very much like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h263kmf2/13/)

**CSS**

```
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#menu li {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:75px;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:150px;
    background:#000;
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu a {
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

NOTE- Inline block means that spacing is affected by whitespace in the HTML. There are various methods for dealing with this detailed in other SO questions & answers.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation as to why this works?

Comment: And an explanation why is not exactly centered p.s: http://jsfiddle.net/h263kmf2/11/ ;)

Comment: Making something `inline-block` means it is affected by text alignment of it's parent.

Comment: Not exactly centered because of the default `padding-left` applied on `<ul>` (as explained in my answer)

Comment: Shall we delete the comments to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, which doesn't depend on your menu size.

Please note `<ul>` have a default left padding you need to remove (unless you're using a CSS reset).

```css
#menu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
#menu ul{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu li{
  display:block;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:75px;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:150px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#000;
  float: left;
}   
#menu a{
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">  
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="#">Apples</a> 
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">Oranges</a>
    </li> 
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: I have used a css reset

Answer (score 0):

In `#menu li` remove `float:left;` and add `margin:auto;`.

In order to keep both items in a single line, use `display: inline-block;` on the `#menu li` and center the parent ul element with an auto width and margin.